# PlaidML Environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plaidml

I'm trying to install PlaidML with a specific environment but the correct version of Keras and Tensorflow aren't installed or the correct versions are installed but the PlaidML backend is not used.

My requirements.txt file is

```
scikit-learn
scikit-image
matplotlib
seaborn
ipython
jupyter
scipy
numpy
pandas
pillow
pydot
coremltools==3.0
plaidml==0.6.4
plaidbench==0.6.4
keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==1.14
```

My Python code starts with

```
import os
os.environ["KERA_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
import keras
```

Are there any examples of how to set up PlaidML using specific libraries?

Comment: KERA_BACKEND looks like a typo, it should be KERAS_BACKEND

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you that was the issue.